Did nobody arriving in Moldova from Moscow who had their cash confiscated ask for their money back?
The BBC writes about the alleged Russian vote-buying scheme in Moldova:

when customs officers began finding large amounts of money on passengers arriving via connecting flights from Moscow. People who had never left Moldova before were returning from a few days in Russia with wads of notes.
“Almost everyone had money: 2,000, 3,000, 7,000 euros”, the head of customs at Chisinau Airport, Ruslan Alexandrov, remembers. The amounts themselves were not illegal but the patterns were suspicious.
“There were certain flights: Moscow-Istanbul-Chisinau, Moscow-Yerevan-Chisinau,” the customs chief explains. “Normally people don’t come in with that much money. Not from Moscow.”
So police and prosecutors began seizing the cash. In one day alone they say they scooped $1.5m (£1.2m). No-one ever asked for their money back.

Even if they were mules, I find it hard to believe that nobody asked for 'their' money back. Did the authorities ask them justify the money with some paperwork, or some other hurdle that was hard to pass?

So the background is that Ilan Shor who is located in Russia wants to pay people in Moldova to vote the way he wants and the best way he found to transfer money is to send people with cash on airplanes?

@quarague : it doesn't sound implausible to me.

An article of Le Figaro dated April 2023 said that 150 pro-Russian Moldavians returning from a meeting in Moscow and suspected of “participation in an illegal financing system”. Cash  “coming from obscure sources” and carried out “in the interest of a criminal group”  was seized from Moldovan citizens searched mostly at the airport of the capital Chisinau. As the case may be under investigation, the preventive seizure of money continues.
